# preferred pattern for disposing an object context

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, azure-sql-database, azure-worker-roles

In an Azure worker role is which of the following patterns is recommended for disposing an objectcontext. Also, would using either of these patterns affect the connection pooling in a different way?

```
public override void Run()
{      
    DatabaseObjectContext ctx = new DatabaseObjectContext()                 
    while (condition)
    {
      ctx.Dosomething();   
    }
    ctx.Dispose();
}
```

vs

```
 public override void Run()
 {                        
     while (condition)
     {
      DatabaseObjectContext ctx = new DatabaseObjectContext()  
      ctx.Dosomething();   
          ctx.Dispose();
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ObjectContext is not designed to be a long-lasting object. Consider it rather like an implementation of Unit of Work pattern. So the second option is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to choose between the two (i.e. I cannot or is too complicated to implement as Barlomieij said a UoW pattern), I'd choose the first, removing the ctx.Dispose() at the end and replacing it by wrapping everything in a using statement.

Comment: Just to clarify - If you choose the first the while condition will still be inside the scope of the using statement. So effectively thats one creation of the datacontext right?

Comment: No, .NET will create one datacontext for each loop. Wrapping inside a using will let you tell the framework that the context is disposable, but it is garbage collector responsability to destroy those contexts (i.e. at some time, in memory you could have all the created object contexts, all waiting for garbage collection)